# Why are standard library function names different between Windows and Linux?

Tags: c++, std

I am porting a Windows library to Android (with the GNU Standard C++ Library option, libstdc++-v3) and there seem to be numerous naming differences between the VC and GNU libraries, e.g.:

- `_stricmp` is called `strcasecmp` instead
- `_unlink` is called `unlink`
- `_scalb` is called `scalbn`
- `_finite` is called `isfinite`
- `_isnan` is called `isnan`
- `_itoa` and `itoa` do not seem to exist in GNU C++
- `atoi` does exist, but not `atoi64`

The documentation of both VC and GNU libraries implies that they implement "ISO" C++, for example I can get a few warnings out of VC2008 for not using "ISO C++" names, such as this one: "warning C4996: 'itoa': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _itoa." Similarly GNU's manual says "The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 is an ongoing project to implement the ISO 14882 Standard C++ library".

So how do the libraries end up with these different names? How can I tell which names are more "standard"?

Also, is there an **index** of libstdc++-v3 anywhere, i.e. a simple list of all functions in the library? I can only find a [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/) and the "[source documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/)" which does not appear to offer a list of functions.

Comment: Several of these are not in the C++ standard library, so in those cases, neither is "standard".

Comment: Microsoft is trying to be consistent by naming their non-standard functions with a leading underscore.

Comment: `_atoi64` in MSVC is called `atoll` in GCC.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has very little to do with the C++ standard library. It has more to do with C99 and POSIX.

- `strcasecmp` is a POSIX function that libstdc++ happens to implement. msvcrt typically stays at arm's length from POSIX.
- `unlink` is similar—it's a POSIX function.
- `scalbn` is the name of the function in the C99 standard. MSVC doesn't support C99. However, `scalbn` is part of C++11, so I would expect it to show up in msvcrt eventually.
- `isfinite` and `isnan` are both C99.
- `itoa` is neither C99 nor POSIX. It's a strange beast that just shows up in the night.

I'll also point out what several others have pointed out: it's technically more correct to prefix any functions in the standard library that are actually non-standard with an underscore. That's the reason for the proliferation of underscores in msvcrt.

Comment: So an underscore indicates "compiler specific". Thanks, just one more thing: did you just learn this stuff over time, or is there an easy way to work out whether any given function is POSIX, C99, new in C++11, etc.? Are any functions in both POSIX and C/C++ standards at the same time?

Comment: And I guess all POSIX methods implemented by MSVC have an underscore, while all POSIX methods implemented by GNU do not have an underscore. I will need to define a common name for my code do use, so, do you think it would be better to use an underscore in the common name ("#ifdef LINUX int _unlink(const char* p) {...}") or not ("#ifdef WIN32 int unlink(const char* p) {...}")?

Comment: Oh, and -- sorry I keep thinking of more questions -- are there alternative names that are available in both Windows and Linux? For example, instead of POSIX unlink() or C99 scalbn(), is there a ISO standard C++ function for deleting a file or adding something to the exponent on a floating-point number? Or is there no way to write truly portable C++ code?

Comment: @Qwertie Boost is the best you can get at the moment, and for platforms it doesn't support, a C macro could probably suffice. There is no such thing as 'truly' portable, unfortunately, just very close to portable.

Comment: @Qwertie I Googled for most of this stuff. Note that it's not technically a POSIX function if it starts with an underscore. Alternative shared names usually don't exist, often because the functions may have subtle differences between platforms. That's also why I'd suggest for your own code writing a "platform abstraction layer" with whatever API you want that calls different functions on different platforms (i.e. one .h file overall, one .cpp per platform).

Comment: @Qwertie I've found one reliable way to determine if a function belongs to a particular standard is to read that standard. The most popular approach appears to be opening a question on SO though :P

Comment: @Huw, I notice you didn't include a link to the standard list that you assert is available. I googled for a list before asking the question; I couldn't find one.

Comment: @Qwertie: for C++ questions I find the C++ standard to be the obvious starting point, but that's just me. By Googling "C++ standard" I found http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/standards - hope this helps.

Comment: @Huw, that link does not contain the C++ standard, let alone a list of standard functions. It merely says the standard is available for purchase - no thanks.

Comment: @Qwertie take a look at the POCO libraries.

Answer (score 2):

None of them are standard.  The standard does say that you shouldn't add names, though so that is what the warnings actually mean.  The underscore makes them standards compliant because they won't be confused as something in standard C/C++.

They imply that by adding the underscore that your code will be using something in the standard, but neither version are.

Answer (score 1):

I guess any implementation can call their implementation "ISO standard" if they prepend `_` to the function names and do whatever they want, since those identifiers are *guaranteed* to be reserved to the implementation by the standard. But they are also not guaranteed to be portable either.