# build new project include dll and compiler to so

Tags: dll, .so

I am a question about dll use in linux. I have dll and .h file that work good in windows. But now I need to work this program in linux.  If I write a .cpp file that 
function call the dll file's function. Could I compiler this .cpp file to assembly or to .so file. Then I can use .so file without original dll file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DLL that builds on Windows, then provided the C++ code is portable, it should be possible to compile the same code on Linux to produce a shared library (.so file), which is Linux's equivalent to Windows DLLs.  There is good background on this topic [here](http://gernotklingler.com/blog/creating-using-shared-libraries-different-compilers-different-operating-systems/).

If your source code (i.e. CPP or header files) uses `#include` for headers that are Windows-specific, you will have to make that code portable in order for Linux to build and run it.  One approach is to just try compiling your code on Linux and see what errors arise. If you want to be more proactive, for C++ portability guidelines see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103568/how-to-write-portable-code-in-c).